# Как правильно работать с DNS-записями?

Tags: dns

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть сервер с IP-адресом `111.222.333.444`

Есть домен `example.com`

Домен делегирован на Яндекс. "Яндекс Почта для Домена" работает. Теперь надо связать домен с сервером. Как я понимаю, редактировать DNS-записи теперь надо на стороне Яндекса. Создаю A-запись: 
`@   A   111.222.333.444`

Домен `example.com` открывается. Не могу сказать, сразу ли стал открываться.

С поддоменами всё сложнее. Добавляю запись для домена `sub1.example.com`:
`sub1   A   111.222.333.444` - вроде, сразу стал открываться `sub1.example.com`

Добавляю `sub2   A   111.222.333.444`. Прошло уже какое-то время, но `sub2.example.com` так и не открывается.

Пробовал удалять обе записи для sub1 и sub2. sub1 так и продолжает открываться. 
Я так понимаю, после изменения/добавления записей нужно подождать какое-то время, хотя где-то читал, что обновление записей у Яндекса происходит мгновенно.

Из-за неясности с задержкой не могу быть уверенным в своих действиях, так как непонятно, вступили изменения в силу или нет.

Другой вопрос, можно ли добавить одну запись для всех поддоменов?

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: DNS может тормозить с изменениями и это нормально. В зависимости от TTL в зоне и других факторов обновление может занимать хоть сутки. Не знаю как в интерфейсе управления яндекса, но в конфигах bind можно указать `*   A  111.222.333.444` и это будут все неописанные отдельно поддомены

Comment: Спасибо. Уже пробовал использовать * но это не сработало. Попробую в этот раз подождать подольше.